# Using socket.AF_BLUETOOTH

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, bluetooth, python-sockets

So I was trying to learn using Bluetooth with the socket library by just simply having two devices send each other a message and printing it here are the codes:

```
import socket

bmac = "b8:08:cf:3c:7a:c2"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
server.bind((bmac, 4))
server.listen(1)
print("listening")
connection, addr = server.accept()
print(f"{addr} connected!")

connection.sendall("Hello Bluetooth!".encode())
print(connection.recv(1024))
connection.close()
```

- 

```
import socket

bmac = "b8:08:cf:3c:7a:c2"

connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
connection.connect((bmac, 4))
data = connection.recv(1024)
print(data)
connection.sendall("Hello there!".encode())
connection.close()
```

the first one is working just fine and is printing listening... but not connected the second one is throwing an OSError:

```
C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\bluetooth>python client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\bluetooth\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    connection.connect(("b8:08:cf:3c:7a:c2", 4))
OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

I though that this could be a problem with the MAC address I chose but in my PC's device manager settings there is only one device with the "advanced" section where the MAC address usually is (it is the second one)
[image]

[image]

the Bluetooth is obviously on (I'm not that stupid) and it is discoverable (not that much either) any probable causes of this problem? or any solutions?

Comment: Have you paired the two devices? Not familiar with Windows, it might be "Add Device" in the control panel. It is a good idea to have the server running and listening when you do the pairing. This ensures the Bluetooth Serial Socket is in the list of Bluetooth services on that machine when the client machine pairs with it.

Comment: I am not running the scripts on different devices, I am trying to run the scripts from the same device, could that be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried creating the server on your PC and communicating to it from your phone using an app? (e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&gl=DE)

Comment: Yes! And it actually worked, I am going to try to connect the Python script from my phone using a Python IDE and see if the problem is with the scripts or using the same device.